# How to remap Firefox to always use Cmd key for new tab

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm trying to migrate from Chrome to Firefox under OS X and this issue is extremely annoying. In Chrome pressing the Cmd key is a universal for "do this in a new tab" command. It works for addresses, search and clicking on links.

In Firefox for some reason they decided to use Cmd for new tab when clicking but Alt/Option for new tab when entering something in the address bar.

How can I remap the address bar and search from Alt + Click to Cmd + Click?

Answer (score 0):

You may install [Customizable Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) add-on for Firefox.

Once the add-on is installed, a new tab will appear in the preferences window which allows you to remap/customize or disable most of the shortcuts offered by Firefox.

[image]

Alternatively you can use Middle-click instead.

Comment: I have tried this before, but I cannot find the needed item. How can I set a key for "Open new tab from address bar"?